# Laravel 7 ignore global scope when creating

Tags: laravel, global-scope

I have a model `Publisher` that has a many to many relationship to `Collection`

Both have a property called `approved` that is set to false when initially created

I have a global scope that hides any `Publisher` or `Collection` where `approved === false`

```
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $columnName = $this->tableName ? $this->tableName . '.approved' : 'approved';
        $builder->where($columnName, '=', true);
    }
```

`Publisher` is set up as follows:

```
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::creating(function (Publisher $publisher) {
            $publisher->creator_user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        });

        self::created(function (Publisher $publisher) {
            $collection = Collection::create([
                'approved' => (bool)$publisher->approved,
                'title'    => '',
            ]);

            $collection->publishers()->sync($publisher->id);
        });
```

The problem is that the `Collection::create` works, but does not return the created `Collection` when the global scope is applied. It throws the following error:

```
No query results for model [App\Collection] 12
```

The 12 is the ID of the `Collection` created. It is in the DB as expected, so that part works.

I have tried applying `withoutGlobalScope(ApprovedScope::class)` on the create statement both before and after the `create()` but that doesn't seem to help.

The weird thing is that `$publisher = Publisher::create($request->all());` in my controller does return the created `Publisher` even though it has the same global scope applied to it

Any ideas?

Update: I have narrowed down the issue and it is caused by `Collection` using the koenhoeijmakers/laravel-translatable package. So I am still looking for a way to ignore the scope on this create statement.

Comment: you need to add the code where you want the collection to be returned. That part is missing from your question. If collection::create() is working the issue is when fetching it.

Comment: I added a line where I sync `Collection` and `Publisher` to the pivot table. I know the problem is when fetching it, but it is fetched as part of the `create` statement.

Comment: Updated with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful investigation and some help, it came to light this was the result of the `koenhoeijmakers/laravel-translatable` package on the `Collection`

I have solved the issue by not applying the middleware that applies the `ApprovedScope` on the `store` routes where this was causing issues.